# Загрузка файла(Python+Selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, pytest

Всем доброго времени суток!

Пишу автотест и столкнулся с проблемой.

Вовпрос звучит кратко:
Как загружать файлы при помощи Selenium?

Подробно:
При клике на ссылку, поидее, файл и сам должен скачиваться. И я даже настроил место для загрузки файлов по дефолту.

Но столкнулся с тем, что PDF файлы, при клике на ссылку, не скачиваются, а открываются в новом окне. По итогу загрузка не происходит.

Варианта в голове один:
Использовать requests библиотеку из Python

Как бы вы загрузили файл в данной ситуации? Посоветуйте пожалуйста!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не могу добавить комментарий, к сожалению, поэтому ответом :

Вы уже успели попробовали варианты предложенные в этих вопросах?

- [Selenium Webdriver: How to Download a PDF File with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43149534/selenium-webdriver-how-to-download-a-pdf-file-with-python?rq=1)
- [Downloading a PDF using Selenium, Chrome and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53998690/downloading-a-pdf-using-selenium-chrome-and-python)

Comment: Параметр на открытие pdf внешне ("plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True) со второй ссылки - классный вариант, самому интересно попробовать

Comment: @anasmi По итогу, мне помог ответ из первой ссылки. Видимо ваши навыки поиска выше моих :) Большое спасибо вам! Помог вот этот ответ https://stackoverflow.com/a/54427220/10684871

Answer (score 1):

Не то чтобы решение вашей проблемы, но как вариант хотя бы на то, чтобы порассуждать.
Не так давно искал способ перехода на новую, открытую по ссылке страницу. Вот вариант с переключением на новое окно, которое открывается по клику по ссылке:

```
link.click()
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(getDriver(), 30);
wait.until((WebDriver driver) -> driver.getWindowHandles().size() > 1); // ждём новую вкладку
ArrayList<String> tabs2 = new ArrayList<>(getDriver().getWindowHandles()); // создаём список открытых вкладок
getDriver().switchTo().window(tabs2.get(1)); // Выбор второй вкладки в качестве активной
getDriver().findElement(By.xpath(".//body")).click(); // кликаем по новой закладке, чтобы та стала активной
```

Ну а дальше можно уже попробовать найти кнопку для скачивания. Удачи!